# How to align the video with CSS without compromising the quality?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, ionic-framework

I am making a mobile application for the first time using ionic-react, but having some trouble with the CSS component of it. Can someone please help me figure out how to get this video to cover the entire screen without compromising the quality of the video (so no stretching)?

The way I have it at the moment:
Code:

```
.video-background {
  background: #000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -99;
}
.video-foreground,
.video-background iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}

@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  .video-foreground {
    height: 300%;
    top: -100%;
  }
}
@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  .video-foreground {
    width: 300%;
    left: -100%;
  }
}
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
  .vid-info {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0.5rem;
  }
  .vid-info h1 {
    margin-bottom: 0.3rem;
  }
}
@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
  .vid-info .acronym {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Image:

[image: IPhone X view]

Comment: You'll never be able to include enough media queries to cover all eventualities given the range of devices out there plus a laptop user can set their viewport as they wish. Could you put up a short snippet with HTML that we can run for ourselves and then look at alternative methods?

Comment: I used React-player and this is how it looks

<ReactPlayer
              controls={false}
              className="iframe"
              playing={true}
              fullscreen={true}
              url={cities[selectedCity]?.url}
            />

Comment: Doesn't that just give you video fullscreen (which wont cover the screen if the aspect ratio is different?). I'm not sure now what the problem is - do you want the video to totally fill the screen or do you want the whole video to be in view?

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS's `object-fit: cover` will ensure that the video is expanded/contracted to fit one of the dimensions, cropping either top and bottom or the sides as required to fill the screen without distortion (but obviously of necessity losing some of the video).

(Note: it is not possible to include this as a working Stackoverflow snippet as that would involve an iframe inside the snippet structure so you'll need to try this on your browser)

```
<head>
<style>
.video-background {
  background: #000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -99;
}
.video-foreground,
.video-background iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  object-fit: cover;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="video-background">
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/H8cBGAeEsHY" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</body>
```